# dvips or dvipdf + evince = missing special characters on printout

Tags: pdf, printing, dvi, evince

This started happening fairly recently (sometime between April 7 and May 5). It appears that if I convert a DVI to a PDF (e.g. using `dvipdf`, although I'm not sure what all tools trigger this) and then open the result in [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), it looks fine on-screen, but when I print it, some special characters such as ligatures or some symbols residing in fonts don't make it onto the paper. If I use `pdftex`, or if I print from some other application (including "printing" to PDF and then printing *that* PDF in Evince), this problem doesn't show up.

I first noticed this problem with MusiXTeX output, since the `musixtex` script is using `etex`, `dvips`, and `ps2pdf` by default. All of the note heads and some other font-based symbols, as well as textual ligatures, showed up blank.

Here you can find [a small sample `.tex` file, along with the PDF produced from it and a photo of the page printed from Evince](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmafxHUstFqSJZzUnyQVYxwQKvRbazERW4g5pA2iVnQ3dZ).

EDIT — here's the sample code:

```
\font\rm = cmr17 scaled \magstep 0
\rm
def{}ine define

def{}lect deflect

ef{}fect effect

ef{}f{}icient efficient

af{}f{}liction affliction
\bye
```

So, can anyone help me figure out where the bug is here? I'm just not sure where it is in the chain. Or perhaps there's something missing or misconfigured.

Software versions:

- OS: Gentoo Linux
- TeX: TeX Live 2021-r1, pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22
- dvipsk 2021.1_p20210325-r1
- Ghostscript-GPL 9.56.1
- Evince 42.2
- Poppler 22.05.0
- CUPS 2.4.1

Any others I didn't think of?

Comment: Please post your code on this site. (That usually means a full MWE, i.e. a small, minimal example that actually compiles and shows your problem.) No external links, no screenshots of code.

Comment: @Ingmar I can add the sample code to the question. I linked to the PDF because there is possibly something unusual about it; perhaps people can figure some out by inspecting it. And the photo is an illustration of what is wrong with the output. It's a photo of the printout on paper, *not* a "screenshot of code". The sample is extremely simple and unlikely to have anything wrong with it that would cause this issue. I'm 99.9% certain the problem is in the tools.

Comment: Please post a full, minimal *compilable* example: usually those start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You're assuming I'm using LaTeX. But this is Plain TeX. It does indeed compile with `tex`. It's the exact and entire source of the output I linked to.

Comment: well the only really new thing in your pdf is ghostscript. So I would try to report it there.

Comment: Indeed I was not expecting plain TeX in 2022, although `\bye`  should have been a giveaway … That said, tex -> dvi -> pdf works without issues for me and shows a normal PDF, with working glyphs.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the suggestion. `dvipdf` and `ps2pdf` are indeed both part of Ghostscript, so it's suspect.

@Ingmar It does for me as well, *until I print it this specific way*. That's why it's weird. Using either `pdftex` to create the PDF or something other than Evince to print it avoids the problem.

Comment: The ligatures in the linked PDF printed fine for me from Evince (42.2 / Cups 2.4.1, ghostscript 9.56.1, Poppler 22.05 on Arch). Have you tried from other PDF software like Firefox's pdf.js or from Okular or similar? If you get the problem there, I'd look at your printer and printer driver.

Comment: @frabjous Yes, both of those. Those are included in "things other than Evince" that print it fine. And that's why I'm not sure whether the bug is in Evince or one of the earlier tools in the chain.